# Visual Studio 2015 gives lots of errors right after I click "Install"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

These are the errors I get. Now the thing is I have everything listed there installed, at least that's what Control Panel says. I have no idea what I should do, and I CANNOT uninstall Visual Studio, which appears in Control Panel but I only have the `Change` option. Tried searching on Google, but no luck on finding this exact problem. Checked the logs, got some error code listed there, couldn't find anything related to my problem. I am stuck.

[image][image]

Comment: Did you try clicking the [common issues and workarounds](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025135) link?

Comment: I did. Nothing of use there.

Comment: I recently had a very similar issue and ended up paving the machine. You can try running `vs_{edition}.exe /uninstall /force` as a last resort